# How to match a document with existing array elements in mongodb using java driver

Tags: java, mongodb, mongodb-query

Hello all i am trying to match a document using mongodb java driver for eg :

```
     {
             "fName" : "abc",
             "lName" : "456",
             "dob" : "00",
             "address" : "xyz"
     }
```

with

```
"nameIdentity" : [
     {
             "fName" : "abc",
             "lName" : "def",
             "dob" : "00",
             "address" : "xyz"
     },
     {
             "fName" : "123",
             "lName" : "456",
             "dob" : "00",
             "address" : "789"
     }
```

If i found the document then i don't do anything else add the document. My problem here is if my source document contains fname : abc and lname: 456 this is matching fname in the first set of nameIdentity and lname in the second set of identity. I want this to be a one complete match. I have tried something like this

```
List<Document> nameIdentities = (List<Document>) matchedDocument.get("nameIdentity");
for (int i=0;i<nameIdentities.size();i++)
{
    temp.add(nameIdentities.get(0));
    quBasicDBObject=new BasicDBObject("$and",temp);

}

iterable = mongoDatabase.getCollection("entity").find(updatedDocumentTypeOne);

if (iterable.first() == null)
{
    updateResult = mongoDatabase.getCollection("entity")
                .updateOne(
                    new Document("_id", new ObjectId(objectId)),
                    new Document("$push", new Document("nameIdentity", nameList.get(0))));
                                }
```

any suggestions where am i going wrong?

Comment: No, i saw the above link. My question i different i believe.

Comment: Just trying to clear up your intent here. Are you trying to avoid pushing a new array element if "either " the "fname" **or** "lname" property is matched in another array element? Or are you only looking for a single unqiue property such as "fname" not being present in ant array element? Also what then is the desired response? Report nothing modified, or something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**UPDATE**
You may have to use the aggregation framework.

Maybe something like:

```
List<Bson> filterList = new ArrayList<>();
filterList.add(new BsonDocument().append("nameIdentity.fName", new BsonString("abc") ));
filterList.add(new BsonDocument().append("nameIdentity.lName", new BsonString("456") ));

FindIterable<org.bson.Document> it = collection.find(Filters.and(filterList));
```